# FlexSlider not working with MVC5 Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, flexslider

I am creating a website using MVC5 (we do for all our websites here) and I am trying to integrate the FlexSlider (found here: https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/) into one of my pages.

I can't seem to get it working, the page just displays nothing, yet it appears in the 'Inspect Element' with each image as being 0x0 px.

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider" data-controlnav="thumbnails">
    <ul class="slides">
        @if (Model.CDSContent != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.CDSContent)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="@Html.Raw(item["newsimage"])" alt="Slide 2">
                        <div class="flex-caption">newstitle</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
        </ul>
</div>
```

I also have the JS and CSS linked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lab.mattvarone.com/projects/jquery/totop/css/ui.totop.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://lab.mattvarone.com/projects/jquery/totop/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want / need to use Flexslider ? do you use bootstrap ?

Comment: No particular reason, I am just wanting to create a way to have a few different images (in my case, "news articles") that have thumbnails beside them to scroll between the different articles. Yes I am using Bootstrap. Is there a good way to do it using that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course its a little bit difficult to say why your code is not working.
Have you checked what @Html.Raw(item["newsimage"]) returns ?

But...
You could use a carousel that runs on bootstrap.
The code below i made is to scan a folder for images and then i send them to the view  with a viewbag.

--Controller code Start--

```
var GetSliderImaged = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/SlideShowIndexPage")).Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn));

ViewBag.Sliderimages = GetSliderImaged;
```

--Controller code End--

--View code Start--

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide MTop10 BRadius10 unselectable" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        @{
            var ii = 0;
            foreach (var image in ViewBag.Sliderimages)
            {
                if (ii == 0)
                {
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@ii" class="active"></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@ii"></li>
                }
                ii++;
            }
        }
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner " role="listbox">
        @{
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var image in ViewBag.Sliderimages)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="~/Content/SlideShowIndexPage/@image" alt="@image" title="@image" class="img-responsive AWIndexPageSlideImage" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="~/Content/SlideShowIndexPage/@image" alt="@image" title="@image" class="img-responsive AWIndexPageSlideImage" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            }
        }
    </div>    
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

--View code End--

Just so you know .. the code is not complete but its works for sure if there are images "It does not check if there are no images in the viewbag etc"
But for sure that will be easy to make it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help Creator. I have actually just found another slider (BxSlider) which is using jQuery and apart from displaying thumbnails, it is doing what I need. I'm sure it won't be too hard to find a way to display them. (I am fairly novice/new to the programming side of IT)

Comment: Also for an FYI, I asked one of our developers at work for some help with it and after 2 hours of trying EVERYTHING, we discovered that the reason it wasn't working was because I had linked the page to jQuery twice and it only likes it being linked once. After fixing that, the slider still wasn't displaying correctly. Not sure why but it seemed like too much effort to try and play around with the CSS when there are so many other free sliders out there and this one took less than 5 mins to implement.

Comment: i didn't try it but for sure it would be easy to change the indicators to display Thumbnails. i don't know bxslider but if it works it works :)